# LG DVD writer shows Bluebirds application software everytime

Tags: dvd, windows-server-2008, burning, optical-drive

I bought 4 new LG DVD writers and all four writer shows blurbirds.exe named application inside it. EVen if i insert any cd or DVD it won't detect anything but shows thosde 4 files
only

what should i do

I tried their bluebird removel tool but it is not working

I am using window server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this post](http://www.msfn.org/board/lg-gh22ns50-bluebirds-removal-tool-t135300.html), LG has a firmware update for drive model GH22NS50 [available here](http://www.lge.com/us/support/product/support-product-profile.jsp?customerModelCode=GH22NS50) that removes the Bluebird software.  Make sure your drive model matches before applying this firmware.  If you have a different model, [check LG's site for an updated firmware for your drive](http://www.lge.com/us/support/product/support-product.jsp).

**Edit:** Other things to try:

- Test one of the drives on Windows XP/Vista/Win7 to see if the Server 2008 is getting in the way of your firmware updates working.
- It probably won't help, but try contacting LG support.
- **Return the defective drives to the retailer.**  Get 4 more drives -- consider buying a different model of drive; preferably one without the special Bluebird c**p.
  (This one's my favorite solution to brand-new hardware that's not doing what it's supposed to be doing.)

Comment: Actually the posts say that this happens when the drive is empty but in my case even when i put any cd inside it it won't recognise it and only shows  bluebird four files. Looks like drive is pointing to some other memory inside DVD writer.  EVen when i try to do firmware update it says to me to remove the  disc inside but disc is not there.

Comment: you're right.  sounds like if they aren't taking firmware updates to fix they're likely defective.  have you tried them on winXP or Vista machines?

Comment: no i haven't tried on Vista. I am thinking of replacing them today.
LG wasa good brand for me in the past but from now i won't buy it.
I am thinking of replacing with Liteon DVD writers

Comment: yeah, i've got a new LG GH24 drive that i'm... less than crazy about.  at least it didn't come with the bluebird stuff; that would drive me nuts.